# Template is not rendered with mock data, showing "undefined is not a function" in jasmine spec to Angular2 Application

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**Here is the home component code**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import { LowerCasePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, NgControl, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Ng2Highcharts, Ng2Highmaps, Ng2Highstocks } from 'ng2-highcharts';
import { DashboardService, TruncatePipe,dateFormatterPipe,yyyymmddFormatPipe } from '../shared/index';
import { shareDataService } from '../shared/dashboardservice/shareuserdata';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router,Params } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons, NgbDateStruct, NgbActiveModal, NgbModalRef,NgbDateParserFormatter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


interface udpateEditComment {
  pmComment: string;

}
 interface userinfo{
    userInfo:{
      userID:string
    };
}
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.component.css'],
  providers: [shareDataService]
})


export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  greeting:string = "Enter PIN";
  newName: string = '';
  errorMessage: string;
  dashboardData: any[] = [];
  UserInfo: any[] = [];
  GetReports: any[] = [];
  CurrentReport: any[] = [];
  getdashReportsdata: any[] = [];
  currentUser: any[] = [];
  high: number;
  low: number;
  medium: number;
  pichart: any = {};
  highAlerts: any[] = [];
  mediumAlerts: any[] = [];
  lowAlerts: any[] = [];
  getChartData: any[] = [];
  userinfo1 = {};
  severity: any = "";
  totalPageNumbers: any[] = [];
  selectedReportId: number = 1;
  getAdminMenus: any[] = [];
  pageloader: boolean = true;
  graphPageloader: boolean = false;
  CatPageloader: boolean = false;
  selectedReport: {} = { Title: '', Cat: '' };
  totalCount: number = 0;
  userrole: any = "1";
  pageTitle: any = "Porfolio Dashboard";
  closeResult: string;
  editCommentsData: any[] = [];
  selectedAlertReportID: string = '';
  modalRef: NgbModalRef;
  editCommentPageloader:boolean=true;
  riskheaderData={};
  udpateEditComment: FormGroup;
  userid:any;
  roleID:any;

  queryData: {} = {
    repid: "1",
    roleid: "1",
    reportCat: "PIM",
    totalAlerts: "0"
  }



  /**
   * highcharts
   *
   */
  piechartrender(high, low, mediume, contClass) {
    this.pichart = {

      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        className: contClass,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie',
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 0
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        align: "right",
        itemDistance: 20,
        layout: "vertical",
        y: -50,
        x: -50,
        symbolHeight: 12,
        symbolWidth: 12,
        itemStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'normal'

        },

      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          borderWidth: 0,
          minSize: 10,
          radialGradient: null,
          showInLegend: true,
          size: '95%',
          dataLabels: {

            distance: -20,
            format: '{point.y}',
            style: {
              textShadow: false, color: 'white'
            }
          }

        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Alerts',

        data: [{
          name: 'High',
          y: high,
          color: "#eb3228",
        }, {
          name: 'Low',
          y: low,
          color: "#7b7a79",
        }, {
          name: 'Medium',
          y: mediume,
          color: "#ec8123",
        }]
      }]

    }
  }

  constructor(private route: Router, private aRoute: ActivatedRoute,public DashboardService: DashboardService, public config: shareDataService, private aroute: ActivatedRoute, private modalService: NgbModal,private formatDate:NgbDateParserFormatter) { }

  onRoleChange(roleid: boolean) {

    this.queryData["roleid"] = roleid;
    this.getData(roleid);
    this.userrole = roleid;
     this.riskheaderData.roleid=roleid;
     sessionStorage.setItem("riskHeaderData",JSON.stringify(this.riskheaderData));

  }


  ngOnInit() {


    this.getUserinfo();

  }

  getUserinfo() {
    let userinfo="userInfo={'userID':'"+ this.config.user_id +"'}";
    this.DashboardService.rmdService(this.config.homePageData,userinfo).subscribe(
      userrole => {
        this.userrole = userrole.UserRoles[0].roleid;
        this.queryData["roleid"] = this.userrole;
        this.riskheaderData.roleid=this.userrole;
        sessionStorage.setItem("riskHeaderData",JSON.stringify(this.riskheaderData));
        this.getData(this.userrole);
      }
    )
  }

  getData(roleid) {
    let userinfo="userInfo={'userID':'"+ this.config.user_id +"','roleID':'"+ roleid +"'}";
    this.DashboardService.rmdService(this.config.homePageData,userinfo)
      .subscribe(
      userData => {
        this.dashboardData = userData;
        this.userinfo1 = this.dashboardData;
        //this.shareDataService.setUserinfo(this.dashboardData);
        if (this.dashboardData && this.dashboardData.PIM) {
          this.CurrentReport = this.dashboardData.PIM;
          this.getReportsdata(roleid, this.dashboardData.PIM[0].rptID, 1);
          // this.CurrentReport.push({'reportCat':'PIM'});
          this.selectedAlertReportID = this.dashboardData.PIM[0].rptID;
          this.selectedReport["Title"] = this.dashboardData.PIM[0].rptName;
          this.selectedReport["Cat"] = "PIM";
        }
        else if (this.dashboardData && this.dashboardData.PC) {
          // this.CurrentReport.push({'reportCat':'PC'});
          this.CurrentReport = this.dashboardData.PC;
          this.getReportsdata(roleid, this.dashboardData.PC[0].rptID, 1);
          this.selectedAlertReportID = this.dashboardData.PC[0].rptID;
          this.selectedReport["Title"] = this.dashboardData.PC[0].rptName;
          this.selectedReport["Cat"] = "PC";
        }
        else if (this.dashboardData && this.dashboardData.ET) {
          //  this.CurrentReport.push({'reportCat':'ET'});
          this.CurrentReport = this.dashboardData.ET;
          this.getReportsdata(roleid, this.dashboardData.ET[0].rptID, 1);
          this.selectedAlertReportID = this.dashboardData.ET[0].rptID;
          this.selectedReport["Title"] = this.dashboardData.ET[0].rptName;
          this.selectedReport["Cat"] = "ET";
        }
        else if (this.dashboardData && this.dashboardData.APP_ADV) {
          // this.CurrentReport.push({'reportCat':'APP_ADV'});
          this.CurrentReport = this.dashboardData.APP_ADV;
          this.getReportsdata(roleid, this.dashboardData.APP_ADV[0].rptID, 1);
          this.selectedAlertReportID = this.dashboardData.APP_ADV[0].rptID;
          this.selectedReport["Title"] = this.dashboardData.APP_ADV[0].rptName;
          this.selectedReport["Cat"] = "APP_ADV";
        }
        if (this.dashboardData.CutomizedMenu.length != 0 || !this.dashboardData.CutomizedMenu) {
          this.dashboardData.adminTitle = this.dashboardData.CutomizedMenu[0].itemname;
          this.getAdminMenus = [];
          for (var key in this.dashboardData.CutomizedMenu) {
            if (this.dashboardData.CutomizedMenu.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              let element = this.dashboardData.CutomizedMenu[key];
              if (element["itemlevel"] == 2) {
                if(element['itemid'] == 3 || element['itemname']== "Manage Users"){
                  element["page_link"]="manageuser";
                }
                 if(element['itemid'] == 5 || element['itemname']== "Manage Risk Severity Divergence Rates"){
                  element["page_link"]="severity";
                }

                this.getAdminMenus.push(element);
              }
            }
          }
        }


      },

      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );

  }
  fliterpage(repid, reportCat, reportName) {
    this.queryData["repid"] = repid;
    this.queryData["reportCat"] = reportCat;
    this.queryData["reportName"] = reportName;
    sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.queryData));
    this.route.navigate(['/filter', encodeURI(JSON.stringify(this.queryData))]);
  }
  getReportsdata(roleid, repid, pageNumber:string="1") {
    let reportData="request={'userID':'"+ this.config.user_id +"','rptID':'"+repid+"','TplName':'PIMChart','pageNumber':'"+pageNumber+"','roleID':'"+roleid+"','filtervals':{'IACode':'','branch':'','portfolio':'','account':'','alerttype':'','severity':'','agegroup':''}}";
    this.DashboardService.rmdService(this.config.pieChartData,reportData).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.pageloader = false;
        this.graphPageloader = false;
        this.CatPageloader = false;
        this.getdashReportsdata = data;
        this.userinfo1.graphData = this.getdashReportsdata;
        if (this.getdashReportsdata && this.getdashReportsdata.SeverityDS) {
          this.severity = this.keysToLowerCase(this.getdashReportsdata.SeverityDS);
          let contClass = " ";

          if (this.severity.high[0].totalAlerts != 0) {
            this.highAlerts = this.severity.high[0].totalAlerts;

          } else {
            this.highAlerts = null;
            contClass += " high ";
          }
          if (this.severity.low[0].totalAlerts != 0) {
            this.lowAlerts = this.severity.low[0].totalAlerts;
          } else {
            this.lowAlerts = null;
            contClass += " low ";
          }
          if (this.severity.medium[0].totalAlerts != 0) {
            this.mediumAlerts = this.severity.medium[0].totalAlerts;
          } else {
            this.mediumAlerts = null;
            contClass += " medium ";
          }
          this.totalCount = this.severity.medium[0].totalAlerts + this.severity.low[0].totalAlerts + this.severity.high[0].totalAlerts;
          this.queryData["totalAlerts"] = this.totalCount;
          this.riskheaderData.totalAlerts=this.totalCount;
          sessionStorage.setItem("riskHeaderData",JSON.stringify(this.riskheaderData));
          this.piechartrender(this.highAlerts, this.mediumAlerts, this.lowAlerts, contClass);
        }

        this.getChartData = [];
        for (var key in this.getdashReportsdata.GraphData.Graph_Data) {
          if (this.getdashReportsdata.GraphData.Graph_Data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            let element = this.getdashReportsdata.GraphData.Graph_Data[key];
            //  element["Risk"] = new TruncatePipe().transform(element["Risk"], 10000, "...");
            element["Risk_truncate"] = new TruncatePipe().transform(element["Risk"],['35','...']);
            element["Severity"] = new LowerCasePipe().transform(element["Severity"]);
            // element["alert_id"] = element["Alert ID"];
            this.getChartData.push(element);

          }
        }
        //pagination
        let currentPage = this.getdashReportsdata.PageNumber;
        let numberPerPage = 10;
        let totalPage = 0;
        let totalPageShow = 5;
        this.getdashReportsdata["previous"] = false;
        this.getdashReportsdata["next"] = false;
        // totalPage=Math.ceil(this.getdashReportsdata.TotalPageCount/numberPerPage);
        totalPage = this.getdashReportsdata.TotalPageCount;
        if (currentPage > 1) {
          this.getdashReportsdata["previous"] = true;
        }
        if (currentPage != totalPage) {
          this.getdashReportsdata["next"] = true;
        }
        if (totalPage >= totalPageShow && currentPage >= totalPageShow) {
          this.totalPageNumbers = [1, "...", currentPage - 2, currentPage - 1, currentPage, currentPage + 1, currentPage + 2, "...", totalPage];
        }
        if (totalPage == currentPage) {
          this.totalPageNumbers = [1, "...", currentPage - 4, currentPage - 3, currentPage - 2, currentPage - 1, currentPage];
        }
        if (currentPage == totalPage - 1 || currentPage == totalPage - 2) {
          this.totalPageNumbers = [1, "...", totalPage - 4, totalPage - 3, totalPage - 2, totalPage - 1, totalPage];
        }
        if (totalPage < 5) {
          this.totalPageNumbers = Array(totalPage).fill().map((x, i) => i+1);

        }
        if (totalPage > 5 && currentPage < 5) {
          this.totalPageNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "...", totalPage];
        }
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
  onCategoryChange(reportCat) {
    switch (reportCat) {
      case "1":
        this.selectedReportId = this.dashboardData.PIM[0].rptID;
        this.selectedReport["Title"] = this.dashboardData.PIM[0].rptName;
        this.selectedReport["Cat"] = "PIM";
        this.getReportsdata(this.userrole, this.selectedReportId, 1);
        this.CatPageloader = true;
        if (this.dashboardData) {
          this.CurrentReport = this.dashboardData.PIM;
          this.CurrentReport['reportCat'] = "PIM";
          this.CurrentReport.push({ 'reportCat': 'PIM' });
        }

        break;
      case "2":
        this.selectedReportId = this.dashboardData.PC[0].rptID;
        this.selectedReport["Title"] = this.dashboardData.PC[0].rptName;
        this.selectedReport["Cat"] = "PC";
        this.getReportsdata(this.userrole, this.selectedReportId, 1);
        this.CatPageloader = true;
        if (this.dashboardData) {
          this.CurrentReport = this.dashboardData.PC;
        }

        break;
      case "3":
        this.selectedReportId = this.dashboardData.ET[0].rptID;
        this.selectedReport["Title"] = this.dashboardData.ET[0].rptName;
        this.selectedReport["Cat"] = "ET";
        this.getReportsdata(this.userrole, this.selectedReportId, 1);
        this.CatPageloader = true;
        if (this.dashboardData) {
          this.CurrentReport = this.dashboardData.ET;
        }

        break;
      case "4":
        this.selectedReportId = this.dashboardData.APP_ADV[0].rptID;
        this.selectedReport["Title"] = this.dashboardData.APP_ADV[0].rptName;
        this.selectedReport["Cat"] = "APP_ADV";
        this.getReportsdata(this.userrole, this.selectedReportId, 1);
        this.CatPageloader = true;
        if (this.dashboardData) {
          this.CurrentReport = this.dashboardData.APP_ADV;
        }

        break;
      default:
        this.CurrentReport = this.dashboardData.PIM;
        this.selectedReport["Title"] = this.dashboardData.PIM[0].rptName;
        this.selectedReport["Cat"] = "PIM";
    }
  }


  keysToLowerCase(obj: string | Object | number | boolean) {
    /*if (!typeof (obj) === "object" || typeof (obj) === "string" || typeof (obj) === "number" || typeof (obj) === "boolean") {
      return obj;
    }*/
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var n = keys.length;
    var lowKey;
    while (n--) {
      var key = keys[n];
      if (key === (lowKey = key.toLowerCase()))
        continue;
      obj[lowKey] = this.keysToLowerCase(obj[key]);
      delete obj[key];
    }
    return (obj);
  }

  selectedPage(attr) {
    if (attr != '...') {
      this.graphPageloader = true;
      this.getReportsdata(this.userrole, this.selectedReportId, attr);
    }

  }
  getEditComments(alertid) {
    this.editCommentPageloader=true;
    this.udpateEditComment = new FormGroup({
      ddPmCom: new FormControl(),
      ddTimeRes: new FormControl(),
      additionalPMComment: new FormControl(),
      pm_UpdateExistingComment: new FormControl(),
      lastPMCommentUpdatedBy: new FormControl(),
      lastPMCommentDate: new FormControl(),
      headoff_com: new FormControl(),
      resolutionDate: new FormControl(),
      additionalHeadOfficeComment: new FormControl(),
      hdOff_UpdateExistingComment: new FormControl(),
      lastCommentUpdateBy: new FormControl(),
      lastCommentUpdateDate: new FormControl(),
      alertId: new FormControl(alertid),
    });
    let editcomment="editvals={'rptID':'"+ this.selectedAlertReportID +"','altID':'"+ alertid +"','roleID':'"+ this.queryData["roleid"] +"'}";
    this.DashboardService.rmdService(this.config.editComments,editcomment)
      .subscribe(
      editCommentData => {
        this.editCommentsData = editCommentData;
        this.editCommentPageloader=false;

        let resDate=new dateFormatterPipe().transform(this.editCommentsData.resolutionDate.Text);
        let pmcommentdate=new yyyymmddFormatPipe().transform(this.editCommentsData.lastPMCommentDate.Text);
        let commentupdatedate=new yyyymmddFormatPipe().transform(this.editCommentsData.lastCommentUpdateDate.Text);

       let formatedate=this.formatDate.format()
        this.udpateEditComment = new FormGroup({
          //pm Comments
         ddPmCom: new FormControl({value:this.editCommentsData.Comments["0"].disp_com,disabled:this.editCommentsData.pMComment.Enabled===false}),
        //  txPmComText:new FormControl(this.editCommentsData.txPmComText),
         ddTimeRes: new FormControl({value:this.editCommentsData.Comments["0"].time_to_res,disabled:this.editCommentsData.timeToResolution.Enabled===false}),
          additionalPMComment: new FormControl(this.editCommentsData.additionalPMComment.Text),
          pm_UpdateExistingComment: new FormControl(),
          lastPMCommentUpdatedBy: new FormControl(this.editCommentsData.lastPMCommentUpdatedBy.Text),
          lastPMCommentDate: new FormControl(pmcommentdate),
          //headoffice Comments
          headoff_com: new FormControl({value:this.editCommentsData.Comments["0"].headoff_com,disabled:this.editCommentsData.headOfficeComment.Enabled===false}),
          resolutionDate: new FormControl(resDate),
          additionalHeadOfficeComment: new FormControl(this.editCommentsData.additionalHeadOfficeComment.Text),
          hdOff_UpdateExistingComment: new FormControl(),
          lastCommentUpdateBy: new FormControl(this.editCommentsData.lastCommentUpdateBy.Text),
          lastCommentUpdateDate: new FormControl(commentupdatedate),

          alertId: new FormControl(alertid),
        });

      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
  }
  onSaveComment({ value, valid }: { value: udpateEditComment, valid: boolean }) {
    let resDate= value.resolutionDate;
      resDate=resDate.day+"-"+resDate.month+"-"+resDate.year;
    let savevalue="savevals={'rptID':'"+ this.selectedAlertReportID +"','roleID':'"+ this.queryData["roleid"] +"','userId':'"+ this.config.user_id +"','altID':'"+ value.alertId+"','PMComment':'"+value.ddPmCom+"','TimetoResolution':'"+ value.ddTimeRes+"','AdditionalPMComment':'"+value.additionalPMComment+"','Updateexistingcomment':'"+value.pm_UpdateExistingComment+"','HeadOfficeComment':'"+ value.headoff_com +"','AdditionalHeadOfficeComment':'"+value.additionalHeadOfficeComment+"','UpdateHeadexistingComment':'"+value.hdOff_UpdateExistingComment+"','ResolutionDate':'"+resDate+"'}";
    this.DashboardService.rmdService(this.config.SaveComment,savevalue)
      .subscribe(
      saveComment => {
        alert(saveComment);
        this.modalRef.close(saveComment)
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );

  }

  // open(content,alertid) {
  //    this.getEditComments(alertid);
  //  this.modalRef= this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {

  //     this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
  //   }, (reason) => {
  //     this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
  //   });
  // }
  open(content, alertid) {
    this.getEditComments(alertid);
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content);
    this.modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }


  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }

  openWhatsNew(whatsNew) {
    this.modalService.open(whatsNew).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.whatsNewReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private whatsNewReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }




  model: NgbDateStruct;

  isWeekend(date: NgbDateStruct) {
    const d = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
    return d.getDay() === 0 || d.getDay() === 6;
  }

  isDisabled(date: NgbDateStruct, current: { month: number }) {
    return date.month !== current.month;
  }

}
```

Template is not rendered with mock data, showing "undefined is not a function" in jasmine spec to Angular2 Application

**Below is the Spec file**

```
    import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
    import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
    import { NameListService, DashboardService, TruncatePipe } from '../shared/index';
    import { shareDataService } from '../shared/dashboardservice/shareuserdata';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, NgControl, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Ng2Highcharts, Ng2Highmaps, Ng2Highstocks } from 'ng2-highcharts';
    import { Header } from '../shared/header/index';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

describe('Home Component Test Case', () => {
let fixture:any;  
  let homeComponent:any;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HomeComponent,Header,Ng2Highcharts],
      imports:[RouterModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,NgbModule.forRoot()],
      providers:[]
    });

    TestBed.overrideComponent(HomeComponent, {
        set: {
          providers: [{ provide: DashboardService, useClass: MockDashboardService },
                    {provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter},
                    {provide: shareDataService, useClass: MockSharedDataService},
                    {provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute}
          ]
        },
      }).compileComponents().then( () => {
         fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
         homeComponent = fixture.componentInstance;        

      homeComponent.dashboardData = {
          "UserInfo": [
            {
              "empCode": 3049,
              "loginID": "311243935",
              "userLastName": "Rao",
              "userFirstName": "Ramesh",
              "active": true,
              "language": "E",
              "userName": "Ramesh Rao"
            }
          ],
          "UserRoles": [
            {
              "roleid": 1,
              "ROLENAME": "Investment Advisor",
              "IAcode": "B49,DLA,FXF,KPN,LZ2,M72,NNL,NNS,P5J,P7Q,P7T,PHL,TL7",
              "branchCode": "301,311,421,423,439,544,631,647,736,771,806",
              "REF_ID": "PIM"
            }

          ]

        };  
        homeComponent.pageloader = false;

       homeComponent.getData= function(roleid){

        };
        console.log(homeComponent);
        console.log("------------------------------");
        console.log(fixture.nativeElement);
  });

 })); 

  it('Home component instance should be defined and template should be rendered', async(() => {  

     expect(homeComponent).toBeDefined();   
      fixture.detectChanges();
     expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#dashboard_data').length).toBe(1);

  }));




});
```

**While Executing "fixture.detectChanges()" it is throwing below error:**

```
> Failed: undefined is not a function
>     TypeError: undefined is not a function
>         at HomeComponent.getUserinfo (C:/Users/323126953/Desktop/prjt/dist/dev/app/home/home.component.js:9:7509)
>         at HomeComponent.ngOnInit (C:/Users/323126953/Desktop/prjt/dist/dev/app/home/home.component.js:9:7150)
>         at DebugAppView._View_HomeComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal
> (HomeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:44:82)
>         at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (C:/Users/323126953/Desktop/prjt/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9
> 566:18)
>         at DebugAppView.detectChanges (C:/Users/323126953/Desktop/prjt/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9671:48)
>         at ViewRef_.detectChanges (C:/Users/323126953/Desktop/prjt/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7668:24)
>         at ComponentFixture._tick (C:/Users/323126953/Desktop/prjt/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:277:3
> 6)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code of the HomeComponent? Specifically for the getUserInfo method.

Comment: Hi Pedro, in the above code i have put my home component code.